# Trying to adapt TensorFlow's MNIST example gives NAN predictions

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm playing with TensorFlow, using the 'MNIST for beginners' example ([initial code here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_softmax.py)). I've made some slight adaptions:

```
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets(FLAGS.data_dir, one_hot=True)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

# Create the model
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)

# Define loss and optimizer
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)

fake_images = mnist.train.images.tolist() 

# Train
tf.initialize_all_variables().run()
for i in range(10):
  batch_xs, batch_ys = fake_images, mnist.train.labels
  train_step.run({x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})

# Test trained model
print(y.eval({x: mnist.test.images}))
```

Specifically, I'm only running the training step 10 times (I'm not concerned about accuracy, more about speed). I'm also running it on all the data at once (for simplicity). At the end, I'm outputting the predictions TF is making, instead of the accuracy percentage. Here's (some of) the output of the above code:

```
 [  1.08577311e-02   7.29394853e-01   5.02395593e-02 ...,   2.74689011e-02
    4.43389975e-02   2.32385024e-02]
 ..., 
 [  2.95746652e-03   1.30554764e-02   1.39354384e-02 ...,   9.16484520e-02
    9.70732421e-02   2.57733971e-01]
 [  5.94450533e-02   1.36338845e-01   5.22132218e-02 ...,   6.91468120e-02
    1.95634082e-01   4.83607128e-02]
 [  4.46179360e-02   6.66685810e-04   3.84704918e-02 ...,   6.51754031e-04
    2.46591796e-03   3.10819712e-03]]
```

Which appears to be the probabilities TF is assigning to each of the possibilities (0-9). All is well with the world.

My main goal is to adapt this to another use, but first I'd like to make sure I can give it other data. This is what I've tried:

```
fake_images = np.random.rand(55000, 784).astype('float32').tolist()
```

Which, as I understand it, should generate an array of random junk that is structurally the same as the data from MNIST. But making the change above, here's what I get:

```
[[ nan  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan]
 [ nan  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan]
 [ nan  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan]
 ..., 
 [ nan  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan]
 [ nan  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan]
 [ nan  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan]]
```

Which is clearly much less useful. Looking at each option (`mnist.train.images` and the `np.random.rand` option), it looks like both are a `list` of `list`s of `float`s.

**Why won't TensorFlow accept this array?** Is it simply complaining because it recognizes that there's no way it can learn from a bunch of random data? I would expect not, but I've been wrong before.

Comment: `np.random.rand` produces numbers in the range `[0, 1]`. What is the range of numbers you get from `mnist.train.images`? It's quite likely that some of the intermediate values overflowed or underflowed. I would try printing out the intermediate values, say, the result of `tf.matmul(x, W)` to see if that is the problem.

Comment: `0.5` as learning rate is also pretty big, try `0.01` or less

Comment: @keveman `mnist.train.images[0]` is an array of mostly-0 floats, all in the 0-1 range. While trying to split out the `matmul` as an intermediate calculation, I changed the number of training steps to 2... and suddenly it works, giving the expected ~10% accuracy. I've isolated it to that change that fixed it, which seems to confirm an over/underflow. Thoughts on where that could be or how I could fix it?

Answer (score 2):

What is messing you up is that log(softmax) isn't numerically stable.

[The softmax cross entropy with logits loss](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/nn.html#softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits) is numerically stabilised.

so, you can do

```
activations = tf.matmul(x, W) + b
loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(activations, y)

# only to get predictions, for accuracy or you know, actual forward use of the model
predictions = tf.nn.softmax(activations)
```

I'm to lazy to find the machine learning stack exchange articles on log softmax numerical stability, but you can find them pretty quickly I'm sure.

Answer (score 0):

The real MNIST data contains very sparse data. Most of the values are zero. Your synthetic data is uniformly distributed (see [numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.rand.html)). The W and b trained assume a sparse input. It is possible the model you trained was able to overfit strongly and has very large W weights connected to particular input pixels to allow for good output probabilities (a large post-softmax value needs a large pre-softmax activation). When you feed your synthetic data, all of a sudden, all input magnitudes are much larger than before resulting in very large activations everywhere, possibly causing overflow.

Comment: This helps with the accuracy, but in my testing it didn't fix the `nan` problem.

Comment: See revised answer.

Comment: Makes sense, although this is happening on a freshly-trained model (trained with the random data)